# Редактировать .SVG для анимации - XML

Tags: css, html5, svg, css-animation

Как правильно повернуть диск этого `image`?

Я пытался что-то сделать (попробуйте запустить код), но безуспешно. Происходит биение диска. Но это должно выглядеть так:

[ссылка на GIF](https://mensis.ro/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/Logo-Doors.gif)

Ниже код анимации диска:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
attributeType="XML"
type="rotate"
from="0 50 50"
to="360 50 50"
dur="10s"
repeatCount="indefinite" />
```

Полный код [на pastebin](https://pastebin.com/d7Ur54ZB).

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/59365998/7394871

Answer (score 1):

> [Перевод ответа @Alexandr_TT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59370288/7394871) на вопрос EnSO: [Edit .svg to animate
>   - XML](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59365998/7394871)

### Вариант с вращением изображения SVG в формате base64

Чтобы не происходило биение диска необходимо правильно указать центр вращения.

Сделать это поможет правило CSS:  [transform-box: fill-box;](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-box)

Добавьте в ваше приложение:

```
 #disk{
    transform-origin: center center;
    transform-box: fill-box;
    animation: rotate_disk 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
    100% {
        transform: rotateZ(360deg);
    }
  }
```

---

[CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/pen/wvBoxKV)

Answer (score 1):

### Вариант с вращением  изображения в формате png

Чтобы не смешивать два разных решения и облегчить выбор одного из них, этот вариант оформлен как отдельная тема. 
В первом решении растровые изображения были преобразованы в формат `base64`

Выигрыша от данного решения нет, так как SVG в этом случае ведёт себя как обычное растровое изображение, у которого можно только менять размеры и месторасположение. 
Размер файла при этом решении получился очень большой -`132k`, поэтому его неудобно читать и редактировать.

**Обдумайте  вариант решения анимации растровых изображений.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Растровые изображения можно добавлять внутрь SVG используя тег `<image>`
И использовать для анимации обычные правила `CSS`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="499.968" height="281.232" viewBox="0 0 1920 1080">
<defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        opacity: 0.96;
      }
  #disk{
 transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 animation: rotate_disk 10s linear forwards infinite;
  }

  @keyframes rotate_disk {
   100% {
    transform: rotateZ(360deg);
   }
  }
   
    </style>
  </defs>
<image x="293" y="75" width="1255" height="959" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/34irD.png"/>

<image id="disk" class="cls-1" x="515" y="165" width="815" height="815" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qas6q.png"/> 

<image id="scris" class="cls-1" x="363" y="740" width="1105" height="233" xlink:href=" https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCbha.png"/>
</svg>
```

В этом варианте решения размер файла получился **824 байта** против **132 kб** первого решения.